# Widget that updates itself when Wifi state changes

Tags: android, widget, broadcastreceiver

I'm currently working on a widget that should update itself whenever the WiFi state changes (Connected or Disconnected).

I've got a widget running, and i've created a custom BroadcastReceiver to receive a broadcast whenever the Wifi state changes, and this is all working fine, but i've run into a problem.

The BroadcastReceiver sometimes simply shuts down, so it doesn't receive the broadcasts when needed. I've read on http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html that '*After the onReceive() of the receiver class has finished, the Android system is allowed to recycle the receiver.*'

So that's my best guess at what's going on.. But now i want to know how to stop that?
Basically i want to have my BroadcastReceiver to ALWAYS be alive and listening for broadcasts while the widget is placed on the screen.

Is that doable with a BroadcastReceiver in a widget? Or should i try to use a Service that holds the BroadcastReceiver instead?

Hopefully someone can help me out with this problem.

Comment: Why not use a service then?

Comment: I've got something that works 95% fully implemented, and if there is something easy i can do to push that to 100%, i'd rather do that than implement a service (which i've never done before)

Comment: You set the BroadcastReceiver with Context.registerReceiver() or in the Manifest tag <receiver> ? If you register a BroadcastReceiver instance in the context, when the context that contains the BroadcastReceiver instance die, the BroadcastReceiver instance die too

Comment: I tried both registering the BroadcastReceiver in the manifest, and programmatically, i faced the same kind of issue with both methods.
Programmatically i created and registered my BroadcastReceiver in onEnabled() of my widget, and unregistered it in onDisabled().

Answer (score 0):

If you need get when wifi is connected/disconnected only for the widget, you can try add in the manifest  of the widget the action for wifi connection changes like you add in the BroadcastReceiver in the manifest, because the widget class AppWidgetProvider extends BroadcastReceiver

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And in the widget use the onReceive method

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
        // save the connected state to get in onUpdate
        this.connected = intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED, false);
        // update all widgets
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int appWidgetIds[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, MyWidget.class));
        onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    } else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```